# How to select a specific range from a numpy array in a pythonic way when the bounds are given

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have 3 arrays out of which two are 1d and one is a 2d array.

```
l = [ 2.82839846 -6.30950578 -6.38959391 -0.27519359  2.6869558 ]

u = [ 3.19099915 -5.08752367 -6.24197166  0.23919663  3.41277894 ]

a = [[ 3.15995024 -3.70046728 -5.33644501 -0.27519359  6.59680683  ]
     [ 3.20134879 -4.88752672 -6.3360199   1.18276442  4.67593146  ]
     [ 3.94292226 -3.93983918 -6.38959391  1.30204279  4.76023172  ]
     [ 5.10369086 -6.30950578 -4.88046264  0.30511958  2.6869558   ]
     [ 4.79710151 -3.00969539 -3.35513095  0.79020593  4.15729757  ]
     [ 2.82839846 -5.6875145  -6.21062225  0.04142778  3.64081071  ]
     [ 4.45212618 -3.81156855 -4.7380557   2.52212191  5.13595999  ]
     [ 3.20435142 -3.23760713 -5.70469897  0.91339003  2.72868361  ]]
```

I want to do `l <= a < u` So that I get the below array.

```
r = [[ 2.82839846 -6.30950578 -6.38959391 -0.27519359  2.6869558 ]
     [ 3.15995024  -5.6875145 -6.3360199  0.04142778   2.72868361 ]]
```

Also, if in the resultant array some of the columns have more values than the other then I want the other columns to be filled with 0.

```
    r = [[ 2.82839846 -6.30950578 -6.38959391 -0.27519359  2.6869558 ]
         [ 3.15995024  -5.6875145 -6.3360199   0.04142778   2.72868361 ]
         [ 3.17945666     0          0         0.04032400       0      ]]
```

Is there any efficient pythonic way to do the above

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
a.sort(0)
a[(l <= a) * (a <= u)]

array([ 2.82839846, -6.30950578, -6.38959391, -0.27519359,  2.6869558 ,
        3.15995024, -5.6875145 , -6.3360199 ,  0.04142778,  2.72868361])
```